# Promise Not working on IOS8

Tags: javascript, ios, ios8

I use a Promises to resolve different request form the server and it works fine on most browsers but when I try on IOS8 the promise seems never to be run even though I can see that the request has been made with the right response.

Promises should be supported natively on ios mobile 8 according to the docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

What could be the problem

Comment: according to https://caniuse.com/#search=promise however...

Comment: (take a look at the "async functions" section). could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so i'm not using async functions